# How to use bash script from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, symfony, shell-exec

İ know this question is widely asked but I still can't do this. I have a working bash script. I used the `shell_exec()` method. I tried all cases: bash script and `php` file were in the same directory. Bash script were  in home directory. I am using `PHP 5.4` so, it can't from "safe_mode" error.

Any idea?

```
/**
 * @Route("/ftp")
 * @Template()
 */
public function ftpAction(){

    $output = shell_exec('sh ./test.sh');

    var_dump($output);

    return new Response('ftp :'.$output);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as well as the error you are receiving.

Comment: system(), exec(), etc...

Comment: i added code, but i didn't get error. just not working and get null.  charles, sorry but i can't understood what did you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. (https://serverfault.com/questions/272551/how-do-you-give-execute-permissions-to-apache2-user-and-not-to-everyone-else)

Sorry for that. Thanks for your help.